# python file read() displaying empty line

Tags: python

i am following a series of tutorials (http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex16.html ) online and i am completely stuck. i have looked everywhere for the answer but cannot seem o find the solution. i apologise if this is a silly question and completely obvious but i am a total beginner.

the script below works fine except for one mistake. the .read () command on line 29 returns empty when the script is run.

if anyone could tell me why this is and how i could fix it i would be very happy.

kind regards. :)

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

print "we are going to erase the %r" % filename
print "if you do not want to do that hit ctrl C ( ^c )."
print "if you do want to do that hit return."

raw_input ("?")

print "opening the file....."
target = open (filename, "r+")

print "truncating the file. goodbye!"
target.truncate ()

print "now i am going to ask you for 3 lines"

line1 = raw_input ("line 1:")
line2 = raw_input ("line 2:")
line3 = raw_input ("line 3:")

print "now, im going to write those 3 lines to the %s file:" % filename

target.write ("%s\n%s\n%s" % (line1, line2, line3))

print "now i am going to show you the contents of the file:"

print target.read()


print "and finally we close."
target.close()
```

Comment: What does it print and what do you expect it to print?

Comment: every time i run the script i just type in a, b and c to the raw_input as i've run it so many time now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file cursor has been moved to be *after* your writes.  That is the natural consequence of writing.  If you want to read what you wrote, you need to reset the file cursor back to the beginning of the file:

```
target.seek(0)
```

...subsequent reads will now have access to the text you've put in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Python docs on [Input/Output](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html), especially the parts about the position in the file. When you write into a file, the file position is at the end of whatever you wrote until you tell the OS to look at some other location in the file. After you `flush()` the write to disk, you need to `seek()` back to the beginning of the file to read it:

```
>>> f = open("temp.txt", "a+")
>>> f.write("tj hoitjhiortj hiorjh rioh\n")
>>> f.flush()
>>> f.read()
''
>>> f.seek(0)
>>> f.read()
'tj hoitjhiortj hiorjh rioh\n'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are working with a file object, there is a concept of a "cursor".  It's where you are in the file - think the cursor in any text editor.

After you `write` to the end of the file, your "cursor" is at the end.  You can call `read()` as many times as you want to on that file handle, you're only going to get a blank string back.

One way to do it is to move the cursor back to the start after your `write`:

```
target.write('something')
target.flush() #may or may not be necessary, generally good idea to include it
target.seek(0)
target.read()
```

The more sane way is to use context managers to handle opening/closing file handles for you.  You know that a fresh file handle always has its cursor at the start of the file, so you're fine calling `read` on it without bothering with any `seek` or `flush` nonsense.

```
with open(filename,'w') as w:
    w.write('something')

with open(filename) as r:
    print(r.read())
```